# What is a Togi yoru

Tags: translation

[image: image of manga dialogue, transcribed below]

I'm trying to read manga in Japanese and I don't understand this: 伽夜.
Can someone explain it to me please?

> A : でもこんな時代だからこそ
>   A : 限り有る"生"をより豊かに享受する為にも趣味には正直でないと…
>   A : ね　**伽夜**
>   B : なんでそこで私に振るのよ!?
>   A : またまたそんなこと言って**伽夜**にもご立派な趣味があるんじゃないのー？
>   B : そっそんなもの無いもん！

Comment: If you aren't familiar with furigana yet, you might need to start with some easier reading material.

Comment: Manga usually comes with furigana, for some reason.

Answer (score 5):

It's pretty clearly written as かや, but it seems that it's just the character's name. It does seem that there is a word 夜伽{よとぎ}, so it might be some sort of play on that.

Comment: Arigatou gozaimasu. Orz

Comment: @ShiroNeko please don't forget to mark an answer as accepted if it answers your question adequately.